# Error failed failed running [/bin/sh -c apt update && apt upgrade -y]: exit code: 100 when run visual studio 2022 with docker compose mode

Tags: ubuntu, docker-compose, dockerfile

Hi every one : When i run mode docker compose , i have a "**Error   DT1001  failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apt update && apt upgrade -y]: exit code: 100**" on script **RUN apt update && apt upgrade -y**
i try uninstall after that install docker for desktop but still error. can i help you. thanks
[image]
[image]